# IndexError target is out of bounds

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm working on a custom dataset of images and using a Neural Net to classify them.

The data set is about 6000 images of 58 classes. But on training I keep getting a "target is out of bounds" error.

I've double checked the number of classes and image size but still get the same error.

```
#hyperprams
learning_rate = 5e-4
#3 for RGB values 
in_channel = 3
#classes from data set 
num_classes = 58
# arbitray choice 
batch_size = 32
#total number of epochs used to train the model 
epochs = 3

traffic_dataset = TrafficSigns(csv_file='annotations.csv',
                       root_directory='/Users/*****/Desktop/images/',
                       transform = transforms.ToTensor())
train_size = int(0.8 * len(traffic_dataset))
test_size = len(traffic_dataset) - train_size
train, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(traffic_dataset,
                                            [train_size, test_size])

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train,
                                           batch_size= batch_size, 
                                           shuffle= True, 
                                           num_workers= 4)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, 
                                          batch_size = batch_size, 
                                          shuffle= True, 
                                          num_workers= 4)

#Create a fully connected nn
class Net(nn.Module):
    #use the constructor w/ arguments size of data and number of classes
    def __init__(self, 
                 input_size, 
                 num_classes):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 60)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(60, num_classes)
    #define your forward step function with relu as the non-linear function of the weights
    #x will be the datapassed to the model 
    def forward(self, x):
        x=f.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
#sanity check 
test = Net(2028, num_classes)
x = torch.randn(24, 2028)
print(test(x).shape)

#instantiate the class object of NN
net = Net(2028, num_classes)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
nn_optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), 
                          lr = learning_rate)

#train on multiple epochs using the criterion and gradient decent algorthim estabilished above
for epoch in range(1):
    for i, (data, target) in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(train_loader)):
        data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1)
        #forward
        outputs = net(data)
        loss = criterion(outputs, target)
        #backward propigation
        nn_optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        #gradiant decent choosen
        nn_optimizer.step()
```

Im also using a custom dataset class to import the images and labels.
My first thought was that the class is not iterating over the CSV and images correctly but I can't seem to find where they might be not matching up.

```
class TrafficSigns(Dataset):
    #constructure will need csv file of labels images and the transform function defined above
    def __init__(self, 
                 csv_file, 
                 root_directory, 
                 transform = None):
        self.labels = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_directory = root_directory
        self.transform = transform
    #returns the length 
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
    #get data index by indes
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        image_path = os.path.join(self.root_directory, self.labels.iloc[i,0])
        image = io.imread(image_path)
        y_label = torch.tensor(int(self.labels.iloc[i, 1]))
        
        #if statement needed since transform can be set to None 
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        
        return (image, y_label)
```

Any help would be awesome, thank you.
Here is the full stacktrace error that's getting thrown.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/t_/rcfcs8g56jn7trwnsvmdyh_r0000gn/T/ipykernel_34551/1839343274.py in <module>
     11         #forward
     12         outputs = net(data)
---> 13         loss = criterion(outputs, target)
     14         #backward propigation
     15         nn_optimizer.zero_grad()

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
   1148 
   1149     def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1150         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1151                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1152                                label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   2847 
   2848 

IndexError: Target 125 is out of bounds.
```

Comment: can you give the full stacktrace error so that we can accurately know where the error is?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I added the full trade error

Comment: can you check how many total targets you have and what is the min and max label of targets?

Comment: Oh that was a good catch! I realized the csv file had duplicates and extra column with some useless info that dataloader was trying to index based of the wrong label column. Thank you! I would not have thought to double check the object size.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue where I used sequential model (LSTM) for next sequence prediction. I check data loader where labels contained `-1` because of which cross entropy loss throwing exception. here is my sequence chunks where model found -1 sequence as label in data loader:

[image]

Solved **please check your null rows and remove those or set accordingly.**